# Django Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm attempting to pull a user's organization, and provide a queryset to on a context processor that will get filtered through multiple different filter depending on the menu selection.  The current error I am getting is as titled: `Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:`(followed by the org_name of one of all the organizations databased).  I have no problems until I create a news article and attach an organization.

**organizations model:**

```
class Organizations(models.Model):
org_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
org_admin = models.ForeignKey(User) #Defines the admin user account for editing
org_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
org_phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
org_county = models.ForeignKey(County)
org_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
org_address2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
org_city = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
org_zip = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
org_type = models.ForeignKey(OrgType, blank=True)
sub_org = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True) # defines a heirarchy of organiztions
org_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'pic_folder/', blank=True)
org_web = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
org_facebook = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
org_twitter = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.org_name
```

**news model:**

```
class News(models.Model):
title   = models.CharField(max_length=200)
author = models.ForeignKey(User)
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
content = models.TextField()
date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
category    = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=NEWS_CATEGORIES, blank=True)
news_orgs = models.ManyToManyField(Organizations, blank=True)
news_county = models.ManyToManyField(County, blank=False)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

UserOrgConnections model :

```
class UserOrgConnections(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
orgs = models.ManyToManyField(Organizations)
```

**context processor:**

```
def mynews(request):
now = datetime.now()    
if request.user.is_authenticated(): 
    user = request.user.get_profile()   

    userorgs = UserOrgConnections.objects.filter(user = user)
    print userorgs.values('orgs')

    county = user.county.all()      

MyNews = News.objects.filter(news_orgs__org_name=userorgs)  

promotions = OrgPromotion.objects.filter(organization__org_county=county)
dailyspecials = OrgDailySpecials.objects.filter(organization__org_county=county)        
newsall = MyNews.all().order_by('-date') 
entnews = MyNews.filter(news_county=county, category='E')   
technews = MyNews.filter(news_county=county, category='T')
healthnews = MyNews.filter(news_county=county, category='H')
livingnews = MyNews.filter(news_county=county, category='L')
humornews = MyNews.filter(news_county=county, category='H')
travelnews = MyNews.filter(news_county=county, category='R')
moneynews = MyNews.filter(news_county=county, category='M')
return {
'newsall': newsall, 
'now': now, 
'entnews': entnews, 
'technews': technews, 
'livingnews': livingnews, 
'humornews': humornews, 
'travelnews': travelnews, 
'moneynews': moneynews,
}
```

**The template snippet:**

```
{% for newsall in newsall %}
    {% if newsall.date >= now %} 
            {{ newsall }}
            {{newsall.date }}

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following sequence of code looks suspicious:

```
userorgs = UserOrgConnections.objects.filter(user = user)
MyNews = News.objects.filter(news_orgs__org_name=userorgs)
```

This is effectively asking for a sequence of `News` objects whose `news_orgs.org_name` value is equal to the list of userorgs.  You haven't listed the model for `UserOrgConnections` so it's not possible to determine a solution with the information provided.

Perhaps you should look at the [Django Queryset in operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) which is capable of performing a query which filters on a list.

Comment: You make a valide point.  I posted the UserOrgConnection model as well.  Sorry about that.